# Javascript (ES6) iterable stream

Tags: javascript, stream, iterator, ecmascript-6

Is there a pattern for making a stream iterable using ES6 generators?

See 'MakeStreamIterable' below.

```
import {createReadStream} from 'fs'

let fileName = 'largeFile.txt'
let readStream = createReadStream(fileName, {
  encoding: 'utf8',
  bufferSize: 1024
})
let myIterableAsyncStream = MakeStreamIterable(readStream)

for (let data of myIterableAsyncStream) {
  let str = data.toString('utf8')
  console.log(str)
}
```

I'm not interested in *co* or bluebird's *coroutine* or blocking with *deasync*.

The gold is *MakeStreamIterable* should be a valid function.

Comment: How would you even define that (what is `data`...)? byte-by-byte (that's not what it looks like)?

Comment: data is from readStream.on('data', data => ...)

Comment: I cannot figure out a solution. It does not seem possible, as i see it.

Comment: I don't think you can without *co* and the likes. Why are you against that?

Comment: I am not against promises or co-routines (like co) for generators. I am just interested in iterators for async sources.

Comment: `for...of` is synchronous. You cannot iterate synchronously over an asynchronous data source. There was a proposal for async iterators but it was abandoned for https://github.com/zenparsing/es-observable .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a pattern for making a stream iterable using ES6 generators?

No, this cannot be achieved because generators are synchronous. They must *know* what they are yielding and when. Iteration of an asynchronous data source can only currently be achieved by using some kind of callback-based implementation. So, there is no way to make `MakeStreamIterable` 'a valid function' if what you mean by this is 'a valid function whose result can be given to a `for-of` loop'.

### Streams are Asynchronous

A stream represents a potentially infinite amount of data received asynchronously over a potentially infinite amount of time. If we take a look at the [definition of an iterator on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) we can define in more detail what it is about a stream that makes it 'uniterable':

> An object is an iterator when it **knows how to access items from a collection one at a time**, while **keeping track of its current position within that sequence**. In JavaScript an iterator is an object that **provides a next() method** which returns the next item in the sequence. This method returns an object with two properties: `done` and `value`.

*(Emphasis is my own.)*

Let's pick out the properties of an iterable from this definition. The object must...

1. know how to access items from a collection one at a time;
2. be able to keep track of its current position within the sequence of data;
3. and provide a method, `next`, that retrieves an object with a property that holds the next `value` in the sequence or notifies that iteration is `done`.

A stream doesn't meet any of the above criteria because...

1. it is not in control of *when* it receives data and cannot 'look into the future' to find the next value;
2. it cannot know when or if it has received all data, only when the stream has closed;
3. and it does not implement the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) and so does not expose a `next` method which a `for-of` can utilise.

______

### Faking It(eration)

We can't *actually* iterate the data received from a stream (definitely not using a `for-of`), however we can build an interface that *pretends* to by using Promises (yay!) and abstracting away the stream's event handlers inside a closure.

```
// MakeStreamIterable.js
export default function MakeStreamIterable (stream) {
  let collection = []
  let index = 0
  let callback
  let resolve, reject

  stream
    .on('error', err => reject && reject(err))
    .on('end', () => resolve && resolve(collection))
    .on('data', data => {
      collection.push(data)

      try {
        callback && callback(data, index++)
      } catch (err) {
        this.end()
        reject(err)
      }
    })

  function each (cb) {
    if(callback) {
      return promise
    }

    callback = (typeof cb === 'function') ? cb : null

    if (callback && !!collection) {
        collection.forEach(callback)
        index = collection.length
    }

    return promise
  }

  promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    resolve = res
    reject = rej
  })

  promise.each = each

  return promise
}
```

And we can use it like this:

```
import {MakeStreamIterable} from './MakeStreamIterable'

let myIterableAsyncStream = MakeStreamIterable(readStream)

myIterableAsyncStream
  .each((data, i) => {
    let str = data.toString('utf8')
    console.log(i, str)
  })
  .then(() => console.log('completed'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Things to note about this implementation:

- It is not necessary to call `each` immediately on the 'iterable stream'.
- When `each` is called, all values received prior to its call are passed to the callback one-by-one `forEach`-style. Afterwards all subsequent data are passed immediately to the callback.
- The function returns a Promise which resolves the complete `collection` of data when the stream ends, meaning we actually don't have to call `each` at all if the method of iteration provided by `each` isn't satisfactory.
- I have fostered the false semantics of calling this an iterator and am therefore an awful human being. Please report me to the relevant authority.

Comment: Nice abstraction. Something like this ought to be a built-in.

Answer (score 5):

Soon you are going to be able to use [Async Iterators and Generators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration). In node 9.8 you can use it by running with `--harmony` command line option.

```
async function* streamAsyncIterator(stream) {
  // Get a lock on the stream
  const reader = stream.getReader();

  try {
    while (true) {
      // Read from the stream
      const {done, value} = await reader.read();
      // Exit if we're done
      if (done) return;
      // Else yield the chunk
      yield value;
    }
  }
  finally {
    reader.releaseLock();
  }
}

async function example() {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  for await (const chunk of streamAsyncIterator(response.body)) {
    // …
  }
}
```

Thanks to Jake Archibald for the [examples](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/) above.

Answer (score 3):

### 2020 Update:

It looks like streams will be "natively" iterable in the future - just waiting on browsers to implement it:

- https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#rs-asynciterator
- https://github.com/whatwg/streams/issues/778
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=929585
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1525852
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194379

```js
for await (const chunk of stream) {
 ...
}
```